# IdentifierForVendor will change when updating app?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm making iOS7 app and using UUID by IdentifierForVendor to specific an user.

Now I prepare the first update of my app.

Would you tell me which UUID by IdentifierForVendor will change or will not change when users update my app via app store?

Answer (score 1):

If it's an update, it won't change. If they delete and re-install the app the the identifier is not guaranteed to remain the same, unless the user has other apps of yours installed.